# Is using localStorage in a Vue / Vuex app lazy, as in, literally lazy programming?

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vuex

I'm newish to Vue and I have been finding that localStorage set/get is quicker and easier when I want to pass a temporary variable between routes. e.g. saving an item id from one route to use in an API call in the next route.

I am using Vuex, but it feels like more of a headache... or I guess my thinking is why bother the store with this tiny tidbit, if that makes sense?

Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: [simple state management from scratch](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/state-management.html#simple-state-management-from-scratch). If you app is really simple, inject an object to the Vue instance, and then you can mutate and refer to it. But highly recommend vuex, it's great as your app grows and state becomes more complex. With that said, localStorage saves data to disk, while vuex is in memory. I'd imagine the latter is faster even though the difference might not be noticeable.

Comment: this is an opinion, not an answer. do not think of your code in terms of laziness, there are hacks for everything, you've got to think of it in terms of maintainability. if this app is going to grow, and you forget to control the state of the storage in some module, it can become a problem in the long run. there are easier, safer ways to control the state.